# Pass object's pointer as parameter to DialogBoxParam()

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I would like to pass an object's pointer as the fifth parameter of [`DialogBoxParam()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
INT_PTR WINAPI DialogBoxParam(
  _In_opt_  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_      LPCTSTR lpTemplateName,
  _In_opt_  HWND hWndParent,
  _In_opt_  DLGPROC lpDialogFunc,
  _In_      LPARAM dwInitParam
);
```

Here is my call to `DialogBoxParam()` :

```
MyClass *myObject = new MyClass();
DialogBoxParam(
    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_SELECT_ETC),
    hwnd,
    CallbackDlgProc,
    (LPARAM)&myObject
);
```

And here is one of my tries in `CallbackDlgProc()` (knowing myFile is a public char* member of `myObject`) :

```
BOOL CALLBACK CallbackDlgProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, (CHAR*)((*(MyClass*)lParam).myFile), "Title", MB_OK);
            return TRUE;
        }
        case [...]
    }
}
```

Any idea how I could access and edit `myObject` from `CallbackDlgProc()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass it to `DialogBoxParam`, you use the address-of operator `&` to get a pointer. However, it's already a pointer so you actually pass a *pointer to a pointer* (type `MyClass**`).

Either adjust the code in your callback function for it, or do not use the address-of operator.

Comment: Well that was fast, thank you Lucky Luke. Greetings from an ex Jönköping-er ;)

Answer (score 0):

A more detailed explanation for someone that will not understand the above answer, in the OP's example code you must remove "&" to make it work:

```
DialogBoxParam(
    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_SELECT_ETC),
    hwnd,
    CallbackDlgProc,
    (LPARAM)myObject
);
```

Enjoy.